# Externally download the file Strings.xml?

Tags: android, xml

Hey,  I have a lot of strings data, so I put them into Strings.xml..
The problem is that String.xml now is 5 mb big! So the .apk becomes big.. If I make on the first lunch of my app download the Strings.xml from a server, is it possible to replace a blank one that I put into the .apk with the one that I download after the app installation? Or is it bad to have the Strings.xml so big?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resources are read-only, so you can't replace them.

If you're not using the localization features (-en, -it, -de ...) and you can make your app download only the strings you need (provided you don't need always all of them), I would do that if it's worth it.

However, even if 5mb for a text file is a lot, I don't know if there are actual drawbacks, and in the end it will get compressed when in the apk.

Comment: Well my .apk file 8 mb big.. 5 mbs of them are from the Strings.xml I guess... is it possible to download Strings from the web to the Strings.xml?

Comment: no, Strings.xml is read only. (how big is the uncompressed xml??)

Comment: If I go to my project folder, the Strings.xml is 5,768kb..   
Is it possible to make another .xml file in the Values folder so I can download the Strings from the web to that .xml file?

Comment: @Omar: no, you can't either add things to the apk. having two xml with strings is possible, but of course it only helps if you want to organize the strings.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't replace a file which is embedded into the apk, 
also note that during the building stage, each xmls are converted into a 
binary representation.
Since I don't know nothing about your app I can't tell if is bad to have 
a so big string.xml. maybe I'll take a look at the performance and at the 
memory consumption.